# Error al actualizar dato Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

estoy intentando hacer un update de la tabla desde el formulario, pero estoy recibiendo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer, esta intentando hacer un insert, el controlador es así:

```
function save(){
    $producto["id_producto"] = (int)$this->input->post("id_producto");
    $producto["nombre_producto"]   = $this->input->post("nombre_producto");
    

    $this->adminmodel->producto_save($producto);
    message("success","Datos guardados con éxito");
    redirect(base_url("productos"));
}
```

El modelo así:

```
function producto_save($producto){
    if(isset($producto["id_producto"]) && $producto["id_producto"]>0){
        $this->db->update("ele_producto",$producto,array("id_producto"=>$producto["id_producto"]));
        return $producto["id_producto"];
    }else{
        $this->db->insert("ele_producto",$producto);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

El formulario:

```
<form action="<?=base_url("productos/save") ?>" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_producto" value="{{item_edit.id_producto}}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Producto</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{item_edit.nombre_producto}}" required="" name="nombre_producto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

No sé a que se deberá este problema

Comment: Estas haciendo un save... no un update. Un save manda un INSERT. Y el error se da, por que en el insert esta llegando una clave primaria que ya existe.

Comment: Solo necesitas hacer un pequeño cambio poniendo la condición [UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) eso asegura una actualización de datos cuando la clave existe.

Comment: Gracias, funcionó de maravilla